# Updating NULL fields with values

Tags: sql, sql-update, firebird, firebird-3.0

I have a simple table that was populated without complete data and an integer field was not used immediately, so it has over 20,000 null values. I simply want to change every record with a NULL value to 1. The table has only 2 columns, ID and XTIMES. ID is already populated. XTIMES is not. So, using FlameRobin I ran this:

```sql
update TBL_HPID h
set h.XTIMES = 1
where h.XTIMES is null
```

It says that I have 20253 rows affected, and I click on "Commit". All looks good.

But, it never changes anything. I can come back the next day and I still have 20253 records with NULL XTIMES values. It isn't just this table either. I have another similar table that exhibits the same behavior.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. This seems like a very simple thing. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including the necessary DDL and insert statements for the example data, and the exact statements to update and check the result. Also specify the exact Firebird version you're using.

Comment: Also, you say _"I can come back the next day and I still have 20253 records with NULL XTIMES values."_ Why check only the next day? What happens if you immediately check?

Comment: To show updates work: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=055846a758c971042bb407a9c337fe6f

Comment: is there any other activity that is updating the table?

Comment: I don't think there is going to be any way to reproduce this easily. This works on smaller tables. I actually have 2 tables like this, both with ~65,000 records and ~20,000 null fields. It is a telemetry gathering system that is being fed data constantly. I have shut down the service that feeds the data and tried the same update with the same results. FB is very fast, but I am concerned I may have problems down the road with large manual updates. It does not complain, it displays the results you would expect on a successful update, however not one single record is updated.

Comment: You can use Firebird TraceAPI (with built-in CLI utility or with tools like FBProfiler.sf.net and IBExpert) to see if the server actualyl receives `commit` from the FlameRobin, AND if the transaction being committed is the same or NOT the same as the one doing `update`s (check _transaction handles/IDs_ of `update` and `commit` statements in your TraceAPI log.  You may also `alter` the table and add _not null `check constraint`_ to the column, this would break any agent trying to insert/update null values. Yes, intentionally breaking applications is a harsh measure which may fire back.

Comment: A softer option to validate Pirate's rather likely hypothesis, but requiring more labor, would be _creating an `after insert or update position 99999` trigger_ on that table, that would check wether `NEW.XTIMES is null` and if so would `in autonomous transaction` insert log record into a special table you would create, using `monitoring tables` to investigate client machine, statements and other details, and save them for you, so you would later know who and when did this change.

Comment: It is not natural for a `telemetry gathering system` to record every single event directly into non-realtime OLTP system, like Firebird. A moment Firebird would make a pause for things like garbage collection or network would have a short disconnect - telemetery system would loose many tuples of data. So normal scheme is telemetery saving data rows locally then batch-inserting the whole detached buffer at once. What i am driving to, is that the database you work on is not necessarily the database your system uses to store data, it may be a COPY of it, overwritten every hour for example.

Comment: This is a contradiction (assuming you check it *after* committing): _"it displays the results you would expect on a successful update, however not one single record is updated."_ If not one single record is updated, it would not display the result you would expect. I agree with Arioch 'The, it sounds like you are updating a system that gets refreshed or replaced from another source, and therefor your updates disappear on the next sync.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ...or just commits a wrong transaction. This might also explain him seeing "good data" while selecting it from the active but never committed tx.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE TBL_HPID h SET h.XTIMES = 1 WHERE ISNULL(is_processed, '') = ''

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).